# Displaying text on only one image at at time in React

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a portfolio page using React and Tailwind. I am trying to get to where when you hover over each image, it will display the text at the bottom of a single image. Right now when I hover over the image, all text displays on all images. How would I fix this? Also, I know there has to be a way to clean this up, I was trying to get it work first. Thank you for and advice you might have!

```
const Experience = () => {
  const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(false);

  const handleMouseOver = () => {
    setIsHovering(true);
  }

  const handleMouseOut = () => {
    setIsHovering(false);
  }

  return (
    <div
      name="experience"
      className="w-full h-screen bg-[#0a192f] text-gray-300"
    >
      <div className="max-w-[1000px] mx-auto flex flex-col justify-center w-full h-full">
        <div>
          <p className="text-4xl font-bold inline border-b-4 border-purple-800">
            Experience
          </p>
          <p className="py-4">Technologies I have worked with</p>
        </div>
        <div className="w-full grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-4 gap-4 text-center py-8">
          <div className="shadow-md shadow-[#040c16] hover:scale-110 duration-500">
            <img
              onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
              onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
              className="w-20 mx-auto"
              src={CssLogo}
              alt="Css Logo"
            />
            {isHovering ? <p className="font-bold">CSS</p> : ""}
          </div>
          <div className="shadow-md shadow-[#040c16] hover:scale-110 duration-500">
            <img
              onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
              onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
              className="w-20 mx-auto"
              src={HtmlLogo}
              alt="HTML logo"
            />
            {isHovering ? <p className="font-bold">HTML</p> : handleMouseOut}
          </div>
          <div className="shadow-md shadow-[#040c16] hover:scale-110 duration-500">
            <img
              onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
              onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
              className="w-20 mx-auto"
              src={JavaScriptLogo}
              alt="Js Logo"
            />
            {isHovering ? (
              <p className="font-bold">JavaScript</p>
            ) : (
              handleMouseOut
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="shadow-md shadow-[#040c16] hover:scale-110 duration-500">
            <img
              onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
              onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
              className="w-20 mx-auto"
              src={MongoLogo}
              alt="Mongo Logo"
            />
            {isHovering ? (
              <p className="font-bold">Mongo DB</p>
            ) : (
              ''
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="shadow-md shadow-[#040c16] hover:scale-110 duration-500">
            <img
              onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
              onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
              className="w-20 mx-auto"
              src={MysqlLogo}
              alt="Mysql Logo"
            />
            {isHovering ? (
              <p className="font-bold">MySQL</p>
            ) : (
              ''
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="shadow-md shadow-[#040c16] hover:scale-110 duration-500">
            <img
              onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
              onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
              className="w-20 mx-auto"
              src={NodeLogo}
              alt="Node Logo"
            />
            {isHovering ? (
              <p className="font-bold">Node JS</p>
            ) : (
              ''
            )}
          </div>
```

Comment: if it were me, I'd use css. since the p element is within the div, if you set it with visibility: hidden by default, you can then set a :hover rule that overrides the hidden. if you want to really use the setHovering however, I'd separate each section in its own component. the problem right now is that hovering is true for all checks at once.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of text elements, but only one state value:

```
const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(false);
```

So either *all of them* are "hovering" or *all of them* are "not hovering".  Instead of a boolean, you might use some kind of identifier.  For example:

```
const [hoveringID, setHoveringID] = useState();
```

And update the state to an identifier:

```
const handleMouseOver = (id) => {
  setHoveringID(id);
}

const handleMouseOut = () => {
  setHoveringID(undefined);
}
```

And pass some ID to those handlers:

```
onMouseOver={() => handleMouseOver(1)}
```

(Use a different ID for each element, of course.)  And use that state to determine if *that* element is "hovering":

```
{hoveringID === 1 ? <p className="font-bold">CSS</p> : ""}
```

---

Taking it a step further, this all becomes *much* easier if you refactor all of that repeated code.  Create data for your component:

```
const sections = [
  {
    id: 1,
    src: CssLogo,
    alt: "Css Logo",
    hoverContent: "CSS"
  },
  //etc...
]
```

And just map over that data:

```
<div className="w-full grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-4 gap-4 text-center py-8">
{
  sections.map(section => (
    <div className="shadow-md shadow-[#040c16] hover:scale-110 duration-500">
      <img
        onMouseOver={() => handleMouseOver(section.id)}
        onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
        className="w-20 mx-auto"
        src={section.src}
        alt={section.alt}
      />
      {hoveringID === section.id ? <p className="font-bold">{section.hoverContent}</p> : ""}
    </div>
  ))
}
</div>
```